# MacBook 2015 (model A1534) Compatible with 2016 Retina Display (model A1534)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display

Here's the scenario- My friend destroys his 12" 2015 retina display macbook (model A1534) and I tell him I can replace the display for him if he buys a new display assembly. However, the display he purchased to replace the old one is a newer, 2016 rose gold edition (still model A1534, though). There are minor differences in the display cables but nothing that hinders the new display from hooking into the logicboard. However, when it is all set up the screen remains black after the start-up chime.

Is is possible that these two parts are incompatible, or must it be the case that I've done something wrong during reassembly (or the new display was Dead on arrival)? Specifically, I am looking at the MacBook 12" Retina Timing Controller (TCON) Board Flex Cable, if anything is inhibiting the computer from working it is probably a connection difference with this cable, which is still being used from the original, as the new one did not come with one.

Else, I am wholeheartedly open to suggestions/advice on how to proceed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhULl.jpg< Pictures of the setup and differences between the models.

Comment: Just a thought, but obtaining parts from a less than 1 year old MBP is probably a component from a machine that suffered damage so (for me at least) the functionality of the display is in question.  That and differences are differences, no matter how "minor" they appear to be.

Comment: Both are true points, I guess I am mainly looking for someone well versed in these new Macbooks to tell me definitively that they are or are not compatible with each other, though I would be quite shocked if apple made incompatible parts with the same model number.

Answer (score 1):

Just an update, I ordered a new Retina Timing Controller (TCON) Board Flex Cable and replaced the old one and the computer is back to perfect condition.  I thought this would be the case since I had a lot of trouble removing it from the original display assembly AND since after the original damage the screen was still getting power (light), but unable to display anything, however after going back and putting the original, damaged display on after the new one didn't get any power, the damaged one wasn't getting power either.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please don't add comments in the _Answer_ field as this is for answers to questions. It looks as though you were just wanting to add an update to your question - if so, you can do this by using the _edit_ link below your question. If on the other hand this **is** an answer, perhaps you could edit it just to make that clearer? At present, your last sentence isn't very clear.